# Policy gradient derivation confusion

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

In the derivation of the policy gradient, I am confused about why the sum of rewards, $r$,  is constant with respect to $\theta$ where $\theta$ is the weights of the neural network used to determine the policy.

[image]

I believe that the second line should have a bracket around both $\pi$ and $r$ because $r$ is dependent on the sequence of actions $a$, and the sequence of $a$ is obviously dependent on the policy $\pi$ **which is ultimately dependent on $\theta$.**

so

$\nabla_\theta r \neq 0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trajectory $\tau$ containing the sequence states and actions $s, a$ is not dependent on the policy $\pi_{\theta}$ because the integral is over *all* possible trajectories in the space, even those which cannot possibly happen under a particular policy, in which case $\pi(\tau) = 0$. It's not as if the trajectory is dependent on the policy.

Comment: Hi Shimao, you have answered my questions about reinforcement learning in the past, do you have any ideas about this question: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8971/how-does-hindsight-experience-replay-learn-from-unsuccessful-trajectories